# UICollectionview self sizing cells autolayout with constant spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I wish to create a uicollectionview which looks like this.

[image: Collectionview]

The height of the cells will be constant, but the width should automatically change dependant on the length of the label text.

FlowLayout:

```
        func prepareFlowLayout() -> UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
    let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 3
    return flowLayout
}
```

Label:

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //label.backgroundColor = .black

    return label
}()
```

Autolayout inside cell:

```
 backgroundColor = .green
    let conView = contentView
    layer.cornerRadius = 5
    clipsToBounds = true
    conView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
        nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
        nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8)
    ])
```

Result as of now:
[image]

Could anyone send me in the right direction for finding a way which would achieve this?

Comment: In this case your cells are sized correctly for their content, but you need them to take up the extra space (divided evenly amongst the cells I assume).  You cannot do this from with in a single cell; you will need to subclass UICollectionViewLayout and calculate the attributes there, since it can consider all of the cells on a row together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is use the `sizeForItemAt` function for check the correct size of the view, depending to the text.

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension <#myCollectionVC#>: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let height: CGFloat = <#myHeight#>

        //Calculate size for current view
        let stringName: NSString = <#myObjects#>[indexPath.row] as NSString
        let width = stringName.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]).width
        let padding: CGFloat = <#yourTotalPaddingSize#>
        return CGSize(width: width + padding, height: height)
    }
}
```

After that, you'll probably want to align left al your views, in that case, you need to create your own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and assigned to your collectionView (select the Collection View Flow Layout in your storyboard, inside your collection view, and change the class name to MyCustomviewLayout) :

```
class <#MyCustomViewLayout#>: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let spacing = CGFloat(<#spacing#>) // spacing between views

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let oldAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        }

        var newAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        var leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
        for attributes in oldAttributes {
            if (attributes.frame.origin.x == self.sectionInset.left) {
                leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left
            } else {
                var newLeftAlignedFrame = attributes.frame
                newLeftAlignedFrame.origin.x = leftMargin
                attributes.frame = newLeftAlignedFrame
            }

            leftMargin += attributes.frame.width + spacing
            newAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
        return newAttributes
    }
}
```